# Executing sharepoint Job on single content db

Tags: timer-jobs

I've added a 2nd site collection with its own content db. My custom timer job now runs twice, I want it to run only once as it sends an email out.

How can I achieve this ?

Here is my code :

I've commented a few lines - contentDb.Sites[0].... (and I cant remember why) Could this be the answer ?

Also in previous post there was mention of 'If (mySiteCollection.ContentDatabase.Id.Equals(contentDbId))' but couldnt successfully target mySiteCollection ?

```
    namespace DT_CustomTimerDriveAlert
{
    class DriveAlert : SPJobDefinition
    {
         public DriveAlert() 

            : base()
        {

        }

        public DriveAlert(string jobName, SPService service, SPServer server, SPJobLockType targetType)

            : base(jobName, service, server, targetType)
        {

        }

        public DriveAlert(string jobName, SPWebApplication webApplication)

            : base(jobName, webApplication, null, SPJobLockType.ContentDatabase)
        {

                    this.Title = jobName;

        }

        public override void Execute(Guid contentDbId)
        {

                  // get a reference to the current site collection's content database

                  SPWebApplication webApplication = this.Parent as SPWebApplication;

                  //SPContentDatabase contentDb = webApplication.ContentDatabases[contentDbId];

                  // get a reference to the "ListTimerJob" list in the RootWeb of the first site collection in the content database

                  // -- SPList Listjob = contentDb.Sites[0].RootWeb.Lists["DT_TimerJob"];



                  SPSite site = webApplication.Sites["http://sp20104/sites/apps"];


                  SPWeb web = site.OpenWeb("mysite");
                  SPList Listjob = web.Lists["mylist"];
```

Answer (score 2):

You want to set the [**SPJobLockType**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.administration.spjoblocktype.aspx), which you've done for one of your constructors - that looks right to me. That's what I've always used. You might find that an **SPJobLockType.Job** is more appropriate, though that's not clear from your code.

Are you sure you don't have two timer jobs defined? Or one job running for 2 content databases that grabs the same content from one of the content DBs?

Though to be honest, from what you're describing, I wonder if a [**SPWorkItemJobDefinition**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.administration.spworkitemjobdefinition.aspx) wouldn't be a better fit. There's a [good post about it here](http://blog.mastykarz.nl/processing-items-work-item-timer-jobs-sharepoint-2010/), but in short, it allows you to register things that you want to process - rather than running on each content database and then checking withing that content db.

Comment: Hi I I've got it working by using SPJobLockType.Job. About the two constructors, I will try to delete :
 public DriveAlert(string jobName, SPService service, SPServer server, SPJobLockType targetType): base(jobName, service, server, targetType)

Thanks

Comment: does `SPJobLockType.Job` actually restrict it to only one content database? if so, how does it know which database? I have set it from `ContentDatabase` to `Job` and it still runs on all content databases... Is there any way around this besides code to check which content database it is currently running on?